# Android - custom listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm learning Android and trying to copy the layout used in [this tutorial](http://android-dev-tips-and-tricks.blogspot.co.il/2014/02/creating-card-ui.html), my adapter is this

```
public class TestListFrag extends ListFragment {
    private static final String TAG = "Test tag";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.AppTitle);

        ArrayList<Items> items = Feed.get(getActivity()).getItems();

        ItemsAdapter adapter = new ItemsAdapter(items);

        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Items i   = ((ItemsAdapter)getListAdapter()).getItem(position);

        Log.d(TAG, i.getfCaption() + " was clicked" + "at Position " + position
                + "row id" + id);
    }

    private class ItemsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Items> {
        public ItemsAdapter(ArrayList<Items> Items) {
            super(getActivity(), R.layout.listview, Items);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                        R.layout.list_item_card, null);
            }
            Items i = getItem(position);

            TextView caption = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            caption.setText(i.getfCaption());


            return convertView;

        }

    }

}
```

and listview.xml is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E6E6E6">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and list_item_card.xml is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_card_background"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text line 1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text line 2"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text line 3"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

The view is getting inflated but the problem is that I can't get it to work as shown in the website tutorial above, which is Cards layout, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that the list view in your layout has an improper id.

When you are using a ListFragment, the layout / android expects to have specific ids for certain items inside of the layout file for that fragment (specifically, for the list and empty state). See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) for more information.

The short answer is, change out the id of your list view from `"@+id/list_view"` to `"@id/android:list"`, and it should work.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't help.

Comment: What happens exactly...do you see no list at all?